# How to correctly pre-whiten time series in python

Tags: python, time-series, correlation, arima, autocorrelation

I'm trying to find cross -correlation between two-time series and as it so happens, they are auto-correlated(2), nonstationary and co-integrated. As I read about them, it appears that pre-whitening the series before finding the correlation should be done. But there is no clear process mentioned anywhere on how do I pre-whiten a time-series. I'll be doing it in "python" so if someone can mention even just the steps, it'll be great. R has a nice function "prewhiten()" for this purpose and I was wondering how do I implement it in python.

Answer (score -3):

[This](https://machinelearningmastery.com/white-noise-time-series-python/) might be a good starting tutorial for you.

This code takes care of dependencies and creates a 1000-point series with Gaussian distribution.

```
from random import gauss
from random import seed
from pandas import Series
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot
from matplotlib import pyplot
# seed random number generator
seed(1)
# create white noise series
series = [gauss(0.0, 1.0) for i in range(1000)]
series = Series(series)
# summary stats
print(series.describe())
# line plot
series.plot()
pyplot.show()
# histogram plot
series.hist()
pyplot.show()
# autocorrelation
autocorrelation_plot(series)
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: This talks about what is a white noise seriesand not how do I pre-whiten a particular time series