# How to prewhiten univariate time series in Python?

Tags: python, statistics

I am trying to find the cross-correlation between two time series and it turns out that they are auto-correlated and non-stationary. Reading about them, it seems that you have to pre-whiten the series before finding the correlation. But there is no clear process mentioned anywhere on how to pre-whiten a time series. I'm going to do it in Python so if anyone can mention even the steps, that would be great. R has a nice "prewhiten()" function for this purpose and I was wondering how to implement it in Python.

Comment: 1) read documentation or source code of R's `prewhiten`, or of mathematical theory behind it; 2) understand it; 3) write equivalent code in Python. Have you done steps 1 and 2 yet?

Comment: This is almost literally the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62564708/how-to-correctly-pre-whiten-time-series-in-python

Comment: It seems Python is pretty far behind R on this front, it would be great if someone took on @mkriekger1's suggestions who had the ability to do it. If you implement it please let us know